# What is the difference between ActionError and AcrionMessage?

Tags: struts

What is the difference between ActionError and AcrionMessage ?

Answer (score 0):

IF the ActionError object is not empty, the user is forwarded to the input page. When using ActionMessage, such differentiation is not made - the user is always forwarded normally.

Answer (score 0):

**ActionError** is used by Strut's built-in exception handler. When an exception is raised an ActionError object is created and stored in the request or session scope so it can be accessed by the page being forwarded to.

**ActionMessage** is usually used to return a set of messages from an action to a JSP